# Reading Heart Rate Measurement (x2A37) values

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, heartrate

I have a polar H10, and I would like to read the bpm and rr values, consulting the characteristic specs, I am aware of each byte read from the the notification handle, however, I am still having trouble understanding the values generated. For instance: Here is an example output with the gatt tool [Example output screenshot from the gattool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4DPt.png):

Now, I understand the following: `10 48 2c 03` where (10 Flags => with bit 4 set specifying an RR value exists, 48 => uint8 Heart Rate Measurment value, 032c => uint16 rr-interval)

But I do not understand the following: `10 49 5e 03 96 03` According to the documentation, it says 1 or more rr values are present. But what does this mean? How could I receive two rr values?

Side note: The goal is to extract HRV features from these values.

Comment: Where did you get that documentation? I am looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a Signal with the current heart rate, every Second.

No matter if a heart beat really occured in that second or not. (For Example, someone who is sleeping and got a heart rate of, let's say, about 40 bpm. 60 Seconds / 40 bpm = 1,5 seconds per beat. So if the next heart beat comes 1,5 seconds later that means, that there will be seconds (events that you receive), without a heart beat.)

Example:

10 28 DC 05

10 28

10 28 DC 05...

Now on the contrary, if you are in a very intensive training (for example the final spurt) and you got a very high heart rate of, let's say, 195 bpm. 60 Seconds / 195 bpm = 0,316 seconds per beat. That would mean, that there could be 3 or maybe even 4 beats per second.

Example:

10 C3 3C 01 3C 01 3C 01

10 C3 3C 01 3C 01 3C 01

10 C3 3C 01 3C 01 3C 01...

So the number of heart beats that you receive about every second, could vary between 0 events per second up to (I guess) 4 events.

I hope, I could help.

Comment: @DinaNashaat Does this polar h10 send continuous Real time Live heart rate to our app? or it sends the Stored records? Can you help?

Comment: Does this polar h10 send continuous Real time Live heart rate to our app? or it sends the Stored records? Can you help?

Comment: As long as you are nearby, it sends "a package of data" about every second to your app. If you are too far away, the transmission does NOT continue and those "packages of data" are lost for good. If you come back near enough the transmission continues from that moment on, when you got near enough.

Comment: Stored records: You will only receive the next "package of data" (record) after the receiving method is finished. This means that if you decide (just for example) to display a MessageBox within the receive method and wait 10 minutes before clicking OK and the receive method only ends after that, then you will gradually receive the whole packets with all the stored data (around 60 packets per second if I remember correctly). If you were always close enough to the receiving device, nothing would be lost. I hope I could help.